# opening link from variable Python (urllib2.urlopen) + Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am working with Python 2.7 + urllib2 + Beautifulsoup4

When I have string:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.some-website.com', 'html'))`

It works perfectly, but when I move URl to variable, it is not working.

```
variable = 'http://www.some-website.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(variable, 'html'))
```

error:

```
edit: errcode is: File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
  raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
    ValueError: unknown url type: api/Abc-Abc/def/7/179 –
```

---

#### Solved

problem was that one of the links was only a reference to the server's database.

Comment: Remove 'html' from your code and then test it.

Comment: removing HTML had no effect on that.

Comment: please post the error you are getting.

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original ValueError: unknown url type: api/Abc-Abc/def/7/179 –

Comment: @AzurPazur  I mean to add in your question, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Note: Make sure you add live website like http://vaibhavmule.com not http://some-website.com
variable = 'http://www.some-website.com' # Do not forget 'http' prefix here

# As you used 'html' which is not parser library.
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(variable))
```

This should work.

[Reference](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for using parser library.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it had no effect.

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type raise

 ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original

ValueError: unknown url type: api/Abc-Abc/def/7/179

Comment: Are you adding prefix `http://` or just tell me the URL that you are assigning to variable.

Comment: f.e. this: http://www.itnetwork.cz/diskuzni-forum-java//problem-se-spustenim--jar-souboru-54ee24ced7290
Yes, I am using http://

Comment: When I opened that link it is giving me an error and may be it required to login.

Comment: yeah,thank you very much. The problem was in the link.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
var='http://www.example.com'
variable = urllib2.urlopen(var).read()
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
Soup = BeautifulSoup()
import BeautifulSoup
soup = Soup(variable)
```